# How to play HTML5 video with onClick in reactJS for multiple videos?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video

In my react component I have added video tag like:

```
<video controls ref="video">
  <source src="VIDEO SOURCE" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

And I have added play button like:

```
<button onClick={() => {this.refs.video.play()}}>Play Button</button>
```

This code is working for single video when using `ref`

But i have multiple video in one page so

How to use multiple ref in loop?

Comment: So, Basically you'e asking How to render muti video player - like next and previous button and multiples video at once. Right ?

Comment: No, I need custom play with custom play button for each video

Answer (score 0):

instead of using ref use mapping function of videos and pass video uri to onplay button something like this

```
const [videoURI,setVideoURL] = useState(null)
const _onplayvideo= (video_uri) =>{
setVideoURL(video_uri)
}
 ....
map((res)=>{
return(
 <>
 <Video uri={videoURI} />
 <Button onClick={()=>{_onplayvideo(res.video_uri)}} />
 </>
)
})
```

Comment: I need multiple videos with custom play buttons.

Answer (score 0):

It would Work I guess. Check That

```
 const [AutoPlay, setAutoPlay] = useState({});

 const onClickHandler = id => {
   if (AutoPlay.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
     if (AutoPlay[id] === true) {
      setAutoPlay({...AutoPlay,[id]:false});    
  } else {
    setAutoPlay({...AutoPlay,[id]:true});
  }
} else {
  setAutoPlay({...AutoPlay,[id]:true});
}
}

return(
<>
 {

   Videos &&  Videos.map((result,index)=>{                                                  
     return(
            <>
            <video controls key={index} autoplay={AutoPlay[index]===true}>
            <source 
            src={result.Source} //Whatever The Source is
            type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
           <button onClick={() => onClickHandler(index)}>Play</button>
           </>
          )
          })

 }

</>

 )
```

Comment: I need multiple videos with custom play buttons.

Comment: @Tamilvanan edited the code... I excluded the refs and playing with hasOwnProperty() property.

Comment: Thanks for your code... i have tried and getting error like this "Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component."